# Is it an offence to ignore a portable traffic light

Tags: traffic, england-and-wales

This is  a question about laws regarding traffic lights in the UK.

When companies are carrying out works on or near roads they sometimes put up their own lights to control traffic and keep it flowing.

Is it an offence to ignore the lights, or do they hold the same authority as permanent traffic lights?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portable signs are legal and you have to obey then.

http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1984/27/section/65

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/482498/2-11.pdf

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if there was actual legislation or if you would just be considered to be driving dangerously.